# How to access and edit HTML from a website without any webservice and webapi

Tags: asp.net, web-scraping, web-crawler

I want to access and post the data to a website . 
The Problem is i can't use ant webapi and webservice.
**The requirement is to add the timesheet details of the employee to the employee's portal website**. 
We don't have any **web api or web service for that**.
Someone advised me to check the web scrapers.
I googled the web scraping and but didn't find the adding data to website.

Can someone please suggest .

Comment: Something like SeleniumRC could be a valid option

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have no idea about selenium , i want to confirm if i can do the same in web scraping

Comment: I scraped something like 20 web portals with the help of selenium c# sdk to build a complex dashboard, selenium can help to achieve your task. All the best

Comment: BTW your question is OT for SO sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to open up your chrome developer tools, submit the timesheet details and investigate the call that was made to the employee's portal backend.

Then you can write your own backend and reproduce that call (using `HttpClient` or `RestSharp`).

Don't forget to investigate the authentication as well, as you'll probably gonna have to send a security token together with your request.

Comment: Hi Daan, can you suggest me tool for this.

Comment: To view the call that was made, you can use Google Chrome Developer Tools. Open it up and check the network tab and you'll see the calls that were made.

More info at: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference